# Knockout Mapping toJSON - cannot ignore nested child

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Assume I have a viewModel like below.

```
var data = {
        a: { a1: "a1", a2: "a2" },
        b: "b"
    };
```

I would like to ignore a.a1 and b. So my expected JSON is

```
{"a":{a2:"a2"}}
```

However, on doing this

```
var result = ko.mapping.toJSON(data, { ignore: ["a.a1", "b"] })
```

I am getting result=

```
{"a":{"a1":"a1","a2":"a2"}}
```

Knockout mapping is not ignoring a.a1. Is this a bug in the plugin? It correctly ignored 'b' but why not 'a.a1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names found in the `ignore` array should be the name of the property, regardless of what level it is in the object.  You have to use:

```
{ ignore: [ "a1", "b" ] }
```

Comment: Perfect! so that means I cannot have duplicate property names in my viewmodel. Didnt realize the mapping would impose such a restriction. Much Appreciated Jeff.

Comment: I know this sucks :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had similar ignore list where some "ids" have to be suppressed and others left as is. I wanted to expand on the answer so that people using fromJS can see specific ignores do work

```
var data1 = {
        invoice: { id: 'a1', name: 'a2', type: 'a3'},
        shipping: "b1",
        id:"c1"
};
```

> var resultvm = ko.mapping.**fromJS**(data1, {'ignore':["invoice.id",
>   "ship"]}); ko.applyBindings(resultvm);

Will give you an output as below. Notice that only the id for invoice has been ignored.

> {"invoice":{"name":"a2","type":"a3"},"id":"c1"}

But toJSON gives

Code:

> var result = ko.mapping.**toJSON**(data1, { ignore: ["invoice.id",
>   "shipping"] });

Result:

> {"invoice":{"id":"a1","name":"a2","type":"a3"},"id":"c1"}

Here is my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3b17r0ys/8/